Django HttpReponse: can't change file name (XMLHttpRequest)
I am trying to implement a file download feature via an XMLHttlpRequest. The response is formed as follows:
    response = HttpResponse(entries, content_type='application/text charset=utf-8')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={self.title}.docx'

So, the title should be something like 'Book.docx'. Instead, on every download I get a UUID-like title that is different, wrong, and has no extension, e.g. 'b691dac0-9498-414f-9c5b-a96223998b76'.
Encoding the title with urlquote or .encode() doesn't help.

show us your view as it is unclear what self.title is

@iklinac That doesn't matter, I can insert any plain string there, like 'filename="Book.docx"', the result would still be the same.
